# How to mock scrollIntoView function correctly?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write the unit test cases using react testing library for the below two use effect hooks.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.querySelector('button[data-active="true"]');
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      element?.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'auto',
        block: 'center',
        inline: 'center',
      });
    }, 300);
  
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, [months]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.querySelector('button[data-active="true"]');
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      element?.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'nearest',
        inline: 'center',
      });
    }, 300);

    trackEvent('Click', 'Month Tab');
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, [selectedMonth]);
```

Unit test code:

```
it('scrolls to the active button when months dependency changes', () => {
    // Render the component with the desired initial state
    const { container } = render(
      <BrandProvider theme={theme}>
      <Tabs
        months={months}
        selectedMonth={selectedMonth}
        setSelectedMonth={() => {
          selectedMonth = dateRange.currentMonth;
        }}
      />
      </BrandProvider>,
    );
    expect(container).toBeInTheDocument();
    // Update the months dependency to trigger the useEffect
    act(() => {
      months.push({ key: '04/2022', value: 'Apr 2022' });
    });
  
    // Ensure that the scrollIntoView function was called with the correct parameters
    expect(Element.prototype.scrollIntoView).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      behavior: 'auto',
      block: 'center',
      inline: 'center',
    });
  });
  
  it('scrolls to the active button and tracks event when selectedMonth dependency changes', () => {
    // Mock the trackEvent function


    const trackEvent = jest.mock('../../helpers/analytics', () => ({
      trackEvent: jest.fn(),
    }));
  
    // Render the component with the desired initial state
    const { container } = render(
      <BrandProvider theme={theme}>
        <Tabs
          months={months}
          selectedMonth={selectedMonth}
          setSelectedMonth={() => {
            selectedMonth = dateRange.currentMonth;
          }}
        />
      </BrandProvider>,
    );
  
    // Update the selectedMonth dependency to trigger the useEffect
    act(() => {
      selectedMonth = '10/2021';
    });
  
    // Ensure that the scrollIntoView function was called with the correct parameters
    expect(Element.prototype.scrollIntoView).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'nearest',
      inline: 'center',
    });
  
    // Ensure that the trackEvent function was called with the correct parameters
    expect(trackEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Click', 'Month Tab');
  });
```

But on running test cases , it says no of calls zero
And the scrollIntoView method is not getting called.
Can someone please help me in currently mocking thefunction scrollIntoView.
Please refer the image for the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvsU3.png)